# Struts 2 FreeMarker Template Error stack.findValue('top') is undefined

Tags: struts2

I have another question for Struts2.

I was doing a chart & a datatable. What happens was on the first load of my chart (and clicking the chart data to link to a datatable), it works fine. But when I changed the parameter in my chart and wants to repopulate the datatable, it gives me this error:

```
Error on line 69, column 13 in template/simple/select.ftl
stack.findValue('top') is undefined.
```

It cannot be assigned to itemKey

### The problematic instruction:

```
==> assignment: itemKey=stack.findValue('top') [on line 69, column 13 in
template/simple/select.ftl]
in user-directive s.iterator [on line 59, column 1 in template/simple/select.ftl]
```

### Stacktrace

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Error on line 69, column 13 in template/simple/select.ftl
stack.findValue('top') is undefined.
It cannot be assigned to itemKey
    at freemarker.core.Assignment.accept(Assignment.java:111)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:299)
    at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:130)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:190)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.renderTemplate(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:157)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.mergeTemplate(UIBean.java:559)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:513)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.Annotate_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fselect_005f9(Annotate_jsp.java:1086)
    at org.apache.jsp.Annotate_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(Annotate_jsp.java:629)
    at org.apache.jsp.Annotate_jsp._jspService(Annotate_jsp.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.ja
```

How should I start fixing this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you show the JSP part and describe what you trying to do there?

Comment: It almost sounds like there isn't an S2 request being made, like a JSP is being accessed directly--more information will be needed, but I'd start by looking at precisely what's happening with regards to the update request processing.

Comment: Well basically on my JSP side I have a number of dropdowns and checkbox options, that will generate charts. Then on the chart itself I will also be passing these parameters into another action in struts that does the datatable. Were these input parameters lost when they're passed from one action to another?

Comment: Are you instantiating anything in struts/spring and then changing the referenced object inside a method? Ensure any object that is referenced by a framework is not changed to another referenced object.

Comment: Hi JasonG,

I don't really quite get what you're asking on the second question. But for the first question, yes. Basically on my struts2 framework, what I need to accomplish is that I have a number of parameters to pass to get a chart, then on the chart itself I will click from the chart data, and pass the parameters into the next action to render datatable. What happens this error did not happen until I tried to make the parameter change by selecting something else on the dropdown, (the chart refreshed to the new data and) click on the chart and bam! The error appears. What can be the cause?

Answer (score 7):

OK I know that this is a backdated issue but as much as I struggled my way through looking for solutions, here's what I found through the link [here](http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/jira-Created-WW-3387-FreeMarker-template-error-template-simple-select-ftl-stack-findValue-top-is-und-td3552355.html):

> Null values added in List you are facing
>   Template error..
>
> once again going to check the database or check List values if u added
>   Null values  this problem will come..

Thus, I was checking through my list and bam! It was correct - There was null values inbetween and that struts/ freemaker did now know what to do.

My solution was at my SQL, I selected the field I wanted and to make sure, I added "field  IS NOT NULL".
My page worked out fine happily ever after.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize that the list cannot have null values. Saved my day :)