# Struts2 stack.findValue('top') is undefined Followup

Tags: jsp, struts2, java-5

With regards to my question (link [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837232/struts-2-freemarker-template-error-stack-findvaluetop-is-undefined)), I realized that my problem was with the select function (I believe so it was).

But then again, I don't know where my problem lies because it seem to get the values from one action, but when I linked the value to another action it seem lost.

Is there anywhere that I'm not getting the values to and fro?

Thanks in advance! :)

Here's the code sample (can't disclose too much info haha):

JSP:

```
<s:select id="listA" name="list" headerKey="-1" list="defaultList" listKey="key" listValue="description" theme="simple" cssClass="formfields" />
```

ActionSupport class & Utils Class:

```
this.defaultList= Utils.getThisList(someVectorList);


public static ArrayList getThisList(Vector accesslist) {
    ArrayList dataList = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < accesslist.size(); i++) {
        String elem = (String) accesslist.get(i);

        if (!elem.equals("Fab 35")) {
            dataList.add(new SelectItemsData(elem, elem));
        } else{
            dataList.add(new SelectItemsData(elem, elem));

            dataList.add(new SelectItemsData("Some hard code 1", "Some hard code 1"));
            dataList.add(new SelectItemsData("Some hard code 2", "Some hard code 2"));
            dataList.add(new SelectItemsData("Some hard code 3", "Some hard code 3));
            dataList.add(new SelectItemsData("Some hard code 4", "Some hard code 4"));
        }
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

Comment: i am not still clear what exact problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm still having the stack stack.findValue('top') is undefined. when I changed the value of dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the dataList contains **null** value.